# What is complexity of this max-edge subgraph problem?

Tags: graph-theory, np-hardness, cc.complexity-theory

While discussing the question I had asked [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17412), @NealYoung and I encounter another problem, which is to judge complexity of the problem below:

> Given a connected undirected graph, finding a maximum-size subset of
>   the edges such that every vertex has degree at most two.

I have found some paper on complexity of relative problems. Most of them added more constraint on the original one. [FOS03](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Andrzej_Lingas/f-o.pdf) added "with no odd cycles" and proved that it is NP-hard. [CTW07](http://rnc.r.dendai.ac.jp/~chen/papers/max2edge4.pdf) implied that the variant added "with no 3-cycle" is P referring to another paper (which I failed to find). But I have been unable to judge complexity of the original problem. So how to judge it? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The generalized problem (such that each vertex $v$ has degree at most $b_v$) is called the $b$-matching problem. Chapter 31 of [Schrijver's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540443894) is devoted to the subject. It [can be solved in strongly polynomial time.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019087901785)

The case that $b_v=2$ for every vertex $v$ has been studied, particularly for [providing lower bounds for the traveling salesman problem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2030652.pdf).

Comment: Yeah I see. Thank you for your answer! Maybe you can also give some suggestion about the former question linked on the top?

Comment: @RIC_Eien: My comment is not really serious, but it seems that you are very happy with the answer. If so, why can you not accept it?