# What's complexity of this set problem which looks like "Linear Programming"?

Tags: set-theory, cc.complexity-theory, np-complete

I came up with a problem below, which looks like a linear programming problem:

> Given $n$ sets $S_{1}, S_{2},..., S_{n}$, with constraints of :
>   $$
> \forall i=1, 2, 3,...,n\space\space \left | S_{i} \right |=k;\\
> \left | S_{j_{11}}\bigcup S_{j_{12}} \right |\leqslant k_{1};\\
> \left | S_{j_{21}}\bigcup S_{j_{22}} \right |\leqslant k_{2};\\
> ...\\
> \left | S_{j_{m1}}\bigcup S_{j_{m2}} \right |\leqslant k_{m}.\\
> $$
>   $j_{11},j_{21},...,j_{m1},j_{12},j_{22},...,j_{m2}$ are integers between $1$ and $n$. 
> $k,k_{1},k_{2},...,k_{m}$ are constant positive integers. 
>   The questions is:
>   For a positive integer $q$,Do such $S_{1}, S_{2},..., S_{n}$ exsit, such that $\left| \bigcup_{i}^{n}S_{i} \right |=q$?

I came up with this problem in order to judge complexity of [another graph problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17412). But I failed to find any relative research. So has complexity of this kind of problem been studied? Is this problem NP-Complete or just P? How to judge this problem? Thanks.
By the way, what if $k=2,k_{1}=k_{2}=...=k_{m}=3$?

Answer (score 5):

If I'm not mistaken, the case you specify (with $k =2$, $k_i = 3$) is in P.

Note that the condition $|S \cup S'| \le 3$ is equivalent to saying that $S, S'$ intersect (since $k=2$). Thus, if you think of the $S_i$ as vertices, then the constraints specify a graph $G$, and your problem reduces to finding a graph $H$ such that $G$ is the [line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of $H$.

Verifying that $G$ is indeed a line graph and then finding $H$ can be done in [linear time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#CITEREFRoussopoulos1973).

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not really get the point. Where is $q$ in the reduced problem? Thank you.

Comment: Is that Vertex Number of $H$?

Comment: And what if $G$ is not a line graph?

Comment: $q$ is the number of vertices in $H$, and if $G$ is not a line graph, the procedure will say so. In other words, the problem can be **decided** in polynomial time.

Comment: I cannot agree. The answer depends on not only $G$, but also $q$. In your procedure, however, only "whether $G$ is a line graph or not" would be considered.

Comment: For instance, the minimal non-line graph, $K_{1,3}$. The corresponding $\left | \bigcup_{i}^{4}S_{i} \right |_{max}=5$, instead of "no answer".

Comment: Not sure I understand. why does the procedure return "no answer". in this case, what is the $q$ specified as part of the input ?

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression. In the case above, if $q=2,3,4,5$, the answer is "yes"(such sets do exist), and if $q=6$ or more, the answer is "no". But in your procedure, the answer is "$K_{1,3}$ is not a line graph", instead of "yes or no".

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Fix $q$=5. How do you get a solution if the induced graph is $K_{1,3}$ ?

Comment: $S_{1}$ is the center of $K_{1,3}$, others are $S_{2},S_{3}$ and $S_{4}$. $S_{1}=\{1,2\},S_{2}=\{1,3\},S_{3}=\{1,4\},S_{4}=\{1,5\}$. $\left| \bigcup_{i}^{4}S_{i} \right |=\{1,2,3,4,5\}=5$. Are there any mistakes?

Comment: The graph induced by these sets (viewing each $S_i$ as an edge) is $K_{1,4}$, not $K_{1,3}$.